# One liner for finding the min value of a subset of a list

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I have a method `extract_min` that takes a list of indices `Q` and `d` a list of values.

I want to find the min value in `d` only for the indices in `Q` and return the index in `Q` that has the min value.

The following implemented method works but wondering if there is a one-liner for it.

```py
def extract_min (Q, d):
      R = list(map(lambda x: d[x], Q))
      i = R.index(min(R))
      return Q[i]
```

For example,

```
Q = [1, 2, 4]
d = [0, 8, 14, 5, 7]
extract_min(Q, d) = 4
```

Comment: `d.index(min(d[q] for q in Q))`

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Didn't know you could create a list using the for loop.

Comment: @Mochan It's called a generator expression.